# LINQpad - lprun.exe -ctname refresh context

Tags: sql, sql-server, passwords, linqpad

Is there any way to refresh data context when using lprun.exe -ctname?
When I run my created .linq script via lprun.exe database table created a little bit earlier from outside the script is not "visible" to it.